# Issue with $2\pi$ in exchange-dominated dispersion relation

Tags: dispersion, ferromagnetism

Suppose I have a dispersion formula given by:

$\omega = \frac{2\gamma A k^2}{M_s}$,

where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio, $A$ is the exchange stiffness, $k$ is the wavevector, and $M_s$ is the saturation magnetization.

If I want to compute everything in the radian units, I put $\gamma$ and $k$ in radian. And will expect to get $\omega$ in radian units.

However, I was told that if I decide to work without the radians, I can also put $\gamma$ and $k$ not in radians, and will expect to get $\omega$ in the Hz unit.

But they don't produce the same results. This is probably a very stupid question but I cannot figure it out. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What results *are* produced? Given that $\omega = 2\pi f$, what is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Say, I'm interested in finding $\omega$ for given $k$.

Comment: So, if I elaborate a little: If $k$ is in $m^{-1}$ and $\gamma$ is in $1/(sT)$, I get $\omega$ in $1/s$ unit. However, if I decide to write the same $k$ in the unit rad/m, and use $\gamma$ is in rad/(sT), don't I multiply the RHS by $(2\pi)^3$ whereas the LHS only gets multiplied by $2\pi$?

Comment: I think it might come down to the definition of $\omega$ being an angular velocity in rad/s. If you solve the formula using $k$ and $\gamma$ not in radians, you are solving for a frequency $f$, which relates to $\omega$ via $\omega=2\pi f$. Maybe I am wrong, but could it just be a confusion in definition?